# How to decode special character or HTML entities in react native or JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, react-native, html-parsing

I am getting String from backend which has HTML entities.

`&#8216;` `&#8217;` `&#8220;` `&#8221;` which are `‘` `’` `“` `”` respectivley.

I have used different function such as :-

```
var map = { amp: '&', lt: '<', gt: '>', quot: '"', '#039': "'"};

var output = newsTitle.replace(/&([^;]+);/g, (m, c) => map[c]);
```

output is the parsed string but it is not able to replace the in ***JavaScript*** or ***React Native***. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:-**

I am actually passing this text in

```
<Text numberOfLines={2}>
{output}
 </Text>
```

Comment: Pure JS works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/be6ahnwm/

Comment: @ChrisG in this we have to statically pass each html entities in map.Do we have something in which we can replace it dynamically.

Comment: Yes, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: newsTitle }}`

Comment: I have added some code i.e. how i am passing the text. Can you explain please how to use the attribute you provided. @ChrisG

Comment: I put both options in the fiddle I linked in my first comment.

Comment: @ChrisG you can't set inner HTML in React Native because there is no HTML.  Further, you shouldn't do that in regular, web React as it can open you to XSS attacks.  In the browser you should use either `DOMParser` or a trusted library like `html-entities`.  Here, you need to use a parser library, as the accepted answer states.

Comment: How is `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` supposed to work in react native? We can't use `<p>` in react native!

Answer (score 9):

You can use this library https://github.com/mdevils/node-html-entities

```
const Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;

const entities = new Entities();
console.log(entities.decode('&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;&copy;&reg;&#8710;')); // <>"'&&copy;&reg;∆
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me

```
const decodeHtmlCharCodes = str => {
    const decodedString = document.createElement("textarea");
    decodedString.innerHTML = str;
    return decodedString.value;
}
```

Comment: Please de not post code only answers try to explain what the code does

Answer (score -4):

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  var theString = $('#string').val();
  var varTitle = $('<textarea />').html(theString).text();
  $('#output').text(varTitle);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="string">Enter a html-encoded string to decode</label>
    <input type="text" name="string" id="string" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="decode" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I want to decode it in react native.Dont know how to code jQuery in react native